# Strings and runtime errors. (Program that reverses the order of characters within a string)

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to write a simple program to reverse the order of the last two characters of a string. (If less than 2 characters are present, I just print the string as is)

This is my code,

```
  if(text.length() == 1)
    System.out.println(text);
  else if(text.length() == 2)
    System.out.println(text.substring(1) + text.substring(0,1));
  else
    System.out.println(text.substring(-2) + text.substring(-2,-1) + text.substring(-1));
```

When I try to run the program with an input of any more than three characters, I get a runtime error.

*java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2*

I've run into this before but I usually just code around it for the exceptions. However I think it's time I found out how to eliminate the problem for good.

Any help is most appreciated.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
    String str="Testing";
    int len=str.length();
    String rev = str.substring(0,len-2)+str.charAt(len-1)+str.charAt(len-2);
    System.out.println(rev);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the javadoc of `substring()`? Does it say that it accepts negative indices? It doesn't.

What you want is substrings from `length - 2` to `length - 1`, and from `length -1 to length`. You could also simply use `charAt()`, since you want to extract single characters. And your special case of `text.length() == 2` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative:

```
if(text.length() < 2) {  
   System.out.println(text);  
}  
else {
  char[] textArray = text.toCharArray();  
  char tmp = textArray[text.length() - 1];  
  textArray[text.length() - 1] =  textArray[text.length() - 2];
  textArray[text.length() - 2] = tmp;  
  System.out.println(new String(textArray));  
}
```

Comment: Test your code. Arrays.toString() doesn't do what you think it does.